# Involution on monic cubic polynomials related to nesting/denesting of cubic radicals

Tags: cubics, involutions, roots-of-cubics

Consider the involutive transformation
$$\mathbb{R}^3 \ni (a,b,c) \overset{\phi}{\mapsto} \left( \frac{a + 2 c}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{a^2 + a c + c^2}{3} - b , \frac{a - c}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

Show that if $P(x) = x^3 + 3 a x^2 + 3 b x + c^3$ has real distinct roots $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ then

$$\tilde P(x) = x^3 + 3 \frac{a+ 2 c}{\sqrt{3}} x^2 + 3 \left( \frac{a^2 + a c + c^2}{3} - b\right) x + \left(\frac{a-c}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^3$$

has a unique real root $x_1'$, and

$$\sqrt[3]{x_1'} =\frac{ \sqrt[3]{x_1} + \sqrt[3]{x_2} + \sqrt[3]{x_3} }{\sqrt{3}} $$

Notes:

1. One can check that the discriminant under the transformation $\phi$ changes like $\Delta(\tilde{P}) = - \Delta(P)$,  hence $\tilde P$ does have a unique real root ( and two non-real conjugate).
2. We use $\sqrt{3}$ to  get an involution, not only a bijection.  Loosely we have $(\sqrt[3]{x'_j}) = \mathcal{F}(\sqrt[3] x_j)$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the normalized Fourier transform on triplets.
3. To get all of the roots of $\tilde P$ one can proceed as follows: choose determinations for $\sqrt[3]{x_j}$ with product $c$. Then apply the Fourier transform and raise to the cube ( nice thing is that the order of the components is not relevant). This will work even for polynomials with complex coefficients.
   One can see from here why we have the formula for the discriminant.
4. Formulas with sum of cubic roots equals another cubic root goes back at least to Ramanujan.  Here we have an involution, involving familiar things
5. One could do a similar involution  for cubic forms not necessarily monic-- this is  reducible to the monic case.
6. Posted as a [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Any feedback would be welcome!

$\bf{Added:}$ Here is  [calculation](https://%7BDiscriminant%5B%20x%5E3%20+%203%20(%20a+%202%20c)/Sqrt%5B3%5D%20x%5E2%20+%203%20(%20(a%5E2%20+%20a%20c%20+%20c%5E2)/3%20-b)%20x%20+(%20(a-c)/Sqrt%5B3%5D)%5E3,%20x%5D,%20Discriminant%5B%20x%5E3%20+%203%20a%20x%5E2%20+%203%20b%20x%20+%20c%5E3,%20x%5D%7D) with WA that shows the behavior of the discriminant.

Comment: At first scribble, I expect it ought to be Show that if $P(x) = x^3 + 3 a x^2 + 3 b^2 x + c^3$ has real distinct roots $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ then 

$$\tilde P(x) = x^3 + 3 \frac{a+ 2 c}{\sqrt{3}} x^2 + 3 \left( \frac{a^2 + a c + c^2}{3} - b\right)^2 x + \left(\frac{a-c}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^3$$

Comment: @Will Jagy: Thanks for the feedback,  It is only one power $3$ present, coefficient of $x$ has exponent $1$. check  the discriminants ( link added).

Comment: @Will Jagy: heuristic:  the powers of $\sqrt{3}$ in the denominators

Comment: @orangeskid Noam Elkies has generalized this such that the $5$th root of quintic roots is equal to a quintic root. I’ll post something in a day or two.

Comment: @Tito PiezasIII:  Oh, that sounds interesting!  Waiting for the update! :-)

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: wonder if we get anything at all for your cubic related to theta series.  Btw, can we also get a link to Noah's result?

Comment: @orangeskid I will post something new tomorrow, as the old answer was deleted. Sorry for the delay

Comment: @orangeskid I finally finished the quintic version [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4737700/4781). Sorry for the delay, had busy weekend. And I've added a link to Noam Elkies' result, plus some generalizations.