# On generalizing Ramanujan cosine sums to $\sqrt[5]{x_1}+\sqrt[5]{x_2}+\sqrt[5]{x_3}+\sqrt[5]{x_4}+\sqrt[5]{x_5} = \sqrt[5]{z}$?

Tags: roots, radicals, closed-form, quintics

**I. Cubic**

In 2013, I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/612607/4781) regarding an identity by Ramanujan of form,

$$\sqrt[3]{0+2\cos\tfrac{2\pi}{7}}+\sqrt[3]{0+2\cos\tfrac{4\pi}{7}}+\sqrt[3]{0+2\cos\tfrac{6\pi}{7}} = \sqrt[3]{+5-3\,\sqrt[3]{7}}$$

which later turned out to have a [hidden partner](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1067992/4781),

$$\sqrt[3]{1+2\cos\tfrac{2\pi}{7}}+\sqrt[3]{1+2\cos\tfrac{4\pi}{7}}+\sqrt[3]{1+2\cos\tfrac{6\pi}{7}} = \sqrt[3]{-4+3\,\sqrt[3]{7}}$$

There are infinitely many pairs of identities $\sqrt[3]{x_1} + \sqrt[3]{x_2} + \sqrt[3]{x_3}\,$ where $x_i$ are roots of cubics. The natural question is if this has a deg-$5$ version, starting with the minimal polynomial of $2\cos\frac{2\pi}{11}$.

---

**II. Quintic**

But the analogy only goes so far: it turns out the cosine expressions under the radical in the LHS now involve ***products*** which explains why it was not as easy to find. Let,
\begin{align}a &= 2\cos \frac{2\pi}{11},\quad b = 2\cos \frac{4\pi}{11},\quad c = 2\cos \frac{6\pi}{11},\\
d &= 2\cos \frac{8\pi}{11},\quad e= 2\cos \frac{10\pi}{11}\end{align}

We finally have the analogous identity,

$$\sqrt[5]{a\,b^2e^2}+\sqrt[5]{a^2bd^2}+\sqrt[5]{cd^2e^2}+\sqrt[5]{b^2c^2d}+\sqrt[5]{a^2c^2e} = \sqrt[5]{1-5\big(55+21\sqrt[5]{11}-13\sqrt[5]{11^2}-13\sqrt[5]{11^3}\big)}$$

The minpoly of $(a,b,c,d,e)$ is the well-known,

$$u^5 + u^4 - 4u^3 - 3u^2 + 3u + 1 = 0$$

while that of $x_1=ab^2e^2$ (and its conjugates) is the lesser known,

$$x^5 - 6x^4 - x^3 + 32x^2 + 16x + 1 = 0$$

So equivalently,

$$\sqrt[5]{x_1}+\sqrt[5]{x_2}+\sqrt[5]{x_3}+\sqrt[5]{x_4}+\sqrt[5]{x_5} \\ = \sqrt[5]{1-5\big(55+21\sqrt[5]{11}-13\sqrt[5]{11^2}-13\sqrt[5]{11^3}\big)}$$

The quintic in $x$ is the same given by Noam Elkies (up to sign) in this [2016 MO comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193627/on-quintic-roots-x-11-5x-21-5-dotsx-51-5#comment605130_193627) which, after some trial and error, I figured out has *factorable* roots. And since the quintic in $u$ is a member of the Emma Lehmer family, then by *reversing* this factorization, this leads to the question.

---

**III. Transformation**

The Emma Lehmer quintic is,

$$u^5 + n^2u^4 - (2n^3 + 6n^2 + 10n + 10)u^3 + (n^4 + 5n^3 + 11n^2 + 15n + 5)u^2 + (n^3 + 4n^2 + 10n + 10)u +1=0$$

The case $u=2\cos\frac{2\pi}{11}$ is just $n=-1$. Let $x=u_1u_2^2u_5^2$ for the **appropriate** $u_k$, then we get the new quintic,

$$\frac{(x+1)^5}{(n^4 + 5n^3 + 15n^2 + 25n + 25)} = (n^3 + 3n^2 + 4n + 3) x^4 - (n^4 + 6n^3 + 16n^2 + 23n + 11) x^3 - (n^3 + 5n^2 + 13n + 11) x^2 - (n + 2)x\\$$

The discriminant of both involve the factor $D = (n^4 + 5n^3 + 15n^2 + 25n + 25)^4$. **Examples:**

Let $n=1, D=71^4$, so $x^5 - 776x^4 + 4057x^3 + 2140x^2 + 218x + 1 = 0$, thus,

$$\sqrt[5]{x_1}+\sqrt[5]{x_2}+\sqrt[5]{x_3}+\sqrt[5]{x_4}+\sqrt[5]{x_5} = \sqrt[5]{1-5\big(185 - 113 \sqrt[5]{71} - 65 \sqrt[5]{71^2} - \sqrt[5]{71^3} + 12\sqrt[5]{71^4}\big)}$$

Let $n=2, D=191^4$, so $x^5 - 5916x^4 + 35345x^3 + 12425x^2 + 769x + 1 = 0$, thus,

$$\sqrt[5]{x_1}+\sqrt[5]{x_2}+\sqrt[5]{x_3}+\sqrt[5]{x_4}+\sqrt[5]{x_5} = \sqrt[5]{1-5\big({-299} - 546 \sqrt[5]{191} - 124 \sqrt[5]{191^2} + 20 \sqrt[5]{191^3} + 21 \sqrt[5]{191^4}\big)}$$

and so on.

---

**IV. Questions**

1. Using the roots $x_i$, how do we prove that,
   $$\sqrt[5]{x_1}+\sqrt[5]{x_2}+\sqrt[5]{x_3}+\sqrt[5]{x_4}+\sqrt[5]{x_5} = \sqrt[5]{\beta}$$
   where $\beta$ **is just a quintic** for general $n$? And how to show $\beta$ has the simple form,
   $$\beta = c_0+c_1f+c_2f^2+c_3f^3+c_4f^4$$
   where $f = (n^4 + 5n^3 + 15n^2 + 25n + 25)^{1/5}$ and $c_i$ are just rationals?
2. Since $f$ is actually $f = \pm D^{1/20}$ where we used the *positive* case, does the identity have a partner which uses the *negative* case (like in the cubic version)?

---

***V. Postscript***

With *another* combination of the Lehmer roots described in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/438701/12905), then,

$$\sqrt[5]{y_1}+\sqrt[5]{y_2}+\sqrt[5]{y_3}+\sqrt[5]{y_4}+\sqrt[5]{y_5} = \color{red}0$$

analogous to orangeskid's cubic version in [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4673661/4781).

Comment: Great question!  What would be the property of a quintic for which the sum $\sum x_k^{\frac{1}{5}}$ is $x^{\frac{1}{5}}$ for the unique real root of another quintic?  Is there a pattern that you noticed?

Comment: @orangeskid You know, I thinking of the exact same question: what is the necessary property of a quintic such that its roots behave in the manner as above? Elkies only gave me one example, but he must have used first principles from Galois theory to come up with it. Also, cubics were easier since they were always solvable, but that is one thing to consider: must the quintic be solvable? Second, will a one-real root quintic work as well? Third, I have a feeling these identities come in pairs because of $\pm \sqrt{d}$. So many questions.